# Problems when trying to use ksp/unity3d binaries?

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to use the kerbal space program (ksp) binaries to read in one of the ksp part models, I've added the ksp binaries and UnityEngine.dll under references then I'm doing the following:

```
Planet p = new Planet();
```

Running this gives me the following security exception:

ECall methods must be packaged into a system module.

Can I bypass or fix this?

Edit:

I found out that it's not from the ksp dll but from untiy ones, they use:

```
    [WrapperlessIcall ]
    [MethodImpl (MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
    public extern void StopAllCoroutines ();
```

I need a way to get past this.

Comment: ECall methods must be packaged into a system module. This means all calls of the InternalCall kind can be made only from mscorlib.dll and such but no user created assembly.

Comment: How does unity call them?  I need a way to bypass it.

Comment: How are you importing the ksp DLL into your Unity project?

Comment: @S.Richmond I'm importing it into a normal VS2010 project

Answer (score 0):

`MethodImplOptions.InternalCall` merely indicates that `StopAllCoroutines` is implemented directly in the CLR rather than the BCL (or some other library). Here's [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.methodimploptions.aspx).

As to revising Unity3D not call in to this, you won't be able to bypass it.